# Linkedin public profile not showing with Customize profile URL

Tags: c#, javascript, linkedin-api

am having a problem showing linkedin profiles on my .net website. I was using  the following widget with out any problems for couple months: [widget link](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1072)

Everything was working, but now any public profiles that starts with http://www.linkedin.com/in/ does not show, however http://uk.linkedin.com/pub/ profiles appear fine.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd. Can I suggest you try out the newer Member Profile plugins?

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1278?button-type-inline=true

They have more features and are actively being developed.

And I know it works with my /in/ public profile URL.